# Why I can not execute RegisterRext to config R on the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am try to use R on SQL Server 2022. I try execute the steps described on the Microsoft [Manuell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install-sql-2022?view=sql-server-ver16).

I did everything what is described on the manuell, but I can not do the step: **Configure R runtime with SQL Server**

If I execute this command

`.\RegisterRext.exe /configure /rhome:"%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.2.3" /instance:"MSSQLSERVER"`

Then I get an error: `Error: The rxLibs %ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.2.3\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64 under the given runtime home is not valid for R script type.`

It also weird, my RevoScaleR is installed at location C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\RevoScaleR on my PC not on ProgramFiles

Comment: Other similar error reports I've seen have expanded the %ProgramFiles% variable by the time the path is mentioned in the error. That fact that it does not do this in your case makes me wonder if something is interfering with the variable expansion. Can you try the RegisterRext.exe command again, but with spelling out where the R-4.2.3 directory is rather than relying on the %ProgramFiles% variable?

Comment: The /rhome:"%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.2.3 section is right, if I put this location in my explorer then the location works. I think the problem is that RegisterRext ist on C/user noch in c/program files.

Comment: Try reinstalling R for "All Users" instead of for "Just Me", so it will get installed to Program Files. That will at least eliminate that oddity.

Comment: How to install R for ALL user? during the installation i can in no place select this

Comment: "How to install R for ALL User?" I'm not sure. Several sources suggest running it with the "Run as Administrator" option.

Comment: I did it already no change.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Sorry.